# VBScript for Windows Restart Manager?

Tags: vbscript, application-restart, restartmanager

**Hello,**

Is there VBScript code for **Restart Manager** ([see link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) code to make Microsoft Word close and re-open?

*I used Microsoft Word as an example. I just wanted to send the message to **RestartManager** to close specific application.*

Comment: From documentation: `Purpose: The Restart Manager API can eliminate or reduce the number of system restarts that are required to complete an installation or update.` Maybe i'm wrong, but it does not seem to have nothing to do with Microsoft Word.

Comment: I used Microsoft Word as an example. I just wanted to send the message to RestartManager to close specific application.

Comment: What is the problem with taskkill?

Comment: It terminates the application. For example: if we use taskkill on Microsoft Word it will just terminate it and unsaved data is lost. If we use the RestartManager (this is used in installers) it does close Word but when it i opened again we can find Document recovery panme with the unsaved data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've to read all the RestarManager documentation and get into [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163450.aspx) to catch what you are trying to do.

And you are right. This is a elegant solution to a lot of problems.

BUT, you have two problems.

First, from the [Guidelines for applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Restart Manager, the behaviour observed in word has to be coded in application. Applications need to be aware of the Restart Manager and know how to act. But well, maybe your applications handle it, but ...

Second is Microsoft does not provide a COM interface to the API. From the documentation: `The Restart Manager DLL exports a public C interface that can be loaded by standard or custom installer`.

So, a wrapper needs to be written.

Anyway, for a "scripting" workaround, InnoSetup pascal scripting lets you make use of the Restart Manager API.

Comment: Is there a way to use the "InnoSetup pascal scripting" in VbScripting or VB6?

Comment: AFAIK, no. It offers a simplified access to the underlying Restart Manager, BUT the logic needs to be coded in pascal scripting.